# Pig Latin translator - moving consonant clusters

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

So I have the basics down I just need to find and move the clusters of consonants. any pro tips?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PigLatinTranslator
{

   public static void main (String[] args){

         Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
         String userWord = ""; // original Word
         String userWord1 = "";// transition word
         String Translation = ""; // Translated word
         char x = ' '; //this is a temp. character.

         //Get word from User.
         System.out.println("Hi, Welcome to your personal Pig-Latin Translator!");
         System.out.println("Enter in any word! : ");
         userWord = in.nextLine();
         boolean doAgain = true;
         //begining of Loop 
         do
         {
            //Get the first Character
            x = userWord.charAt(0);

            if("AEIOUYaeiouy".indexOf(x) != -1){
            //Check weather or not the first charcater is a vowell
            System.out.println(userWord + "way");            
            }
            else
            {
            userWord = userWord.substring(1);
            System.out.print(userWord);
            do{
               userWord = userWord.substring(1);
               if ("AEIOUYaeiouy".indexOf(x) != -1){
               System.out.print(x);
               }
               else{
               System.out.print("");
               }
               }while (doAgain);
               System.out.println("ay");
               }
            //Prompt user to quit or continue

            System.out.println("Press Q to quit, or enter another word to be translated: ");
            userWord = in.nextLine();

            } while (!userWord.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function `charIsVowel(Char c)` that checks if a `Char[]` array contains `c`. Then go through your `String` checking if every letter is a vowel until you find one that is. Then move the `substring` of your input from the beginning until the index of the first vowel to the end. Something like this:

```
public static boolean charIsVowel(char c) {
    char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

    for(char ch : vowels) {
        if(c == ch) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

and

```
int index = 0;
for(; index<userWord.length(); index++) {
    if(charIsVowel(userWord.charAt(index))) {
        break;
    }
}

String translation = userWord.substring(index) + "-" + userWord.substring(0, index);
```

Then all you would need to do is add "ay" to the end. So:

```
translation += "ay";
```

The plus side of doing this is that it works no matter if the `String` starts with a vowel or a consonant.

PS: you never use `userWord1`